# Getting 404 when physical location of a file is correct

Tags: url, iis

I have a web application that runs like this:

```
localhost/myapplication/index.html
```

I also have a sub folder "dist" inside of the root folder. When I try navigating to:

```
localhost/myapplication/dist/afile.svg
```

or any js file I get 404. But if I make the dist folder a web folder then localhost:8000/afile.svg doesn't generate 404.

What is the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: this "localhost/myapplication/index.html" works fine?

Comment: I am getting errors down the road, but index.html itself is not creating 404.

Comment: Check the permission on that subfolders/files

Comment: What exactly am I looking for? I briefly looked at myapplication and dist. The security tab looks the same.

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 10. Something just happened. Initially The symptoms were exactly as I am describing. Then for testing purposes I converted dist folder into a web folder to prove that IIS can actually serve files from that folder. After you pointed out to a security issue I checked both root folder and dist folder and they looked the same. Then I went to IIS manager to check anything there. I have removed web application from the dist folder and ran it again. Now localhost/myapplication/dist/afile.svg is working fine. Not getting it.

Comment: Next time use FRT to learn more about the internals, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Could you please tell us the folder structure about your web application? Have you added any url rewrite rule in your web.config?

Comment: The structure is very simple. I have a root folder where index.html is and also have a dist folder for Angular and other front-end files. I have to run the app from the root. I have not added any url rewrite rule.

Comment: I guess that you may have the angular route setting for the svg path, I suggest you could try to check the angular route setting and ignore the svg path. Details, you could refer to this [article](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location).